# Can a value be moved by taking a mutable reference?

Tags: rust

[Playpen](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=82132ae019215582e5d2eae28b70c9a5&version=nightly&backtrace=0)

```
pub trait Skip<I: Iterator> {
    fn skip(&mut self, steps: usize);
}

impl<I: Iterator> Skip<I> for I {
    fn skip(&mut self, mut steps: usize) {
        for _ in self {
            steps -= 1;
            if steps <= 0 {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s  = "abc123def";
    let mut chars = s.chars();
    chars.skip(2);
    println!("{:?}", chars.collect::<String>());
}
```

Error:

```
error: use of moved value: `chars` [--explain E0382]
  --> <anon>:20:22
19 |>     chars.skip(2);
   |>     ----- value moved here
20 |>     println!("{:?}", chars.collect::<String>());
   |>                      ^^^^^ value used here after move
<anon>:20:22: 20:27: note: in this expansion of format_args!
<anon>:20:22: 20:27: note: in this expansion of print! (defined in <std macros>)
<anon>:20:22: 20:27: note: in this expansion of println! (defined in <std macros>)
note: move occurs because `chars` has type `std::str::Chars<'_>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

error: aborting due to previous error
playpen: application terminated with error code 101
```

Comment: The answer explains why this doesn't work and how to work around it, but honestly it's very likely it's better to just use the stdlib's `skip` even if it has a slightly different API (it's an iterator adapter instead of a mutating method).

Comment: @delnan after some experimentation with mutating iterators I concur!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can a value be moved by taking a mutable reference?

No. References do not move the referred-to items. That's one large point of references.

However, [`Iterator::skip`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.skip) does take ownership of the iterator, which is a move:

```
fn skip(self, n: usize) -> Skip<Self>
```

To solve the error, you can... take a mutable reference!

```
chars.by_ref().skip(2);
```

However, note that calling an iterator adapter without using it **does nothing**:

> warning: unused result which must be used: iterator adaptors are lazy and do nothing unless consumed

The *real* problem here is that you aren't calling the `skip` you think you are. If you rename your method to `skip2`, you will see that it works as intended.

This is because method lookup prefers methods that accept the receiver by-value (`self`) before by-reference (`&self`) before by-mutable-reference (`&mut self`).

It's probably a bad idea to pick the same method name as the standard library, especially for iterators, but it's very surprising that a warning isn't printed saying there are multiple applicable methods in scope.

You could use [Universal Function Call Syntax (UFCS)](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ufcs.html) to specify which implementation to call though:

```
pub trait Skip: Iterator {
    fn skip(&mut self, steps: usize) {
        for _ in self.take(steps) {}
    }
}

impl<I> Skip for I where I: Iterator {}

fn main() {
    let s  = "abc123def";
    let mut chars = s.chars();
    Skip::skip(&mut chars, 2);
    println!("{:?}", chars.collect::<String>());
}
```

Comment: There is an error if `Skip::skip` is altered to take `I` directly or if it's called on a mut reference (e.g., `(&mut chars).skip(2)`). The reason that it's legal otherwise is that `Iterator`'s method doesn't require autoref so it's more specific and hence preferred. The lints in `rustc` are pretty bare-bones, but maybe clippy has a lint for this.

Comment: @delnan I wonder if there's an ordering to which method will be chosen (`self` then `&self` then `&mut self`) and the "multiple applicable methods" error only occurs when there are multiple methods in the same class?

Comment: @Shepmaster I think it's phrased in terms of whether autoref is needed, but basically, yes.